# WPF combobox with name and id

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've got a ComboBox which looks like this:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="genreComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="genreComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

I'm binding it to a list of Genres `List<Genre>`, which have a Name and a genreId. Whenever the selection changes, I update the DataContext of a GridView based on that id. So basically I need to display the name, and use the id in a `DataContext=someDB.getStuffById(int genreId);`

I've tried messing around with `getStuffById(genreComboBox.SelectedItem)` and `getStuffById(genreComboBox.SelectedValue)`, setting `DisplayMemeberPath="Name"` and `SelectedValuePath="GenreId"`. Most of the time, the named get displayed.

Whatever I try to get that genreId out, I always get a NullReferenceException.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you bind the combobox in code behind?

Comment: do the following:  genreComboBox.ItemSource = List<Genre>; genreComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; genreComboBox..SelectedValuePath= "Id";  genreComboBox.DataContext = List<Genre>;  Read List<Genre> in a List Object.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to wrap my head around Binding, which is still quite new. Would it make a difference whether I got `ItemSource={Binding}` in XAML and `genreComboBox.DataContext = genreList;` in code behind OR just `genreComboBox.ItemSource = genreList` in code behind?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. I still get a NullReferenceException from albumListView.SelectedValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try calling `getStuffById` by the orignal list of genres.

```
getStuffById(listofGenres[genreComboBox.SelectedIndex].GenreId);
```

Comment: Simple, but neat trick. Still don't know what the actual binding problem was, but this will do just fine.